# How to get the bounds of a PIXI.Graphics instance using pixi.js?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm trying to get the bounding box of a Graphics instance with the world transformation applied using pixi.js

I'm a bit confused using the [PIXI.Graphics documentation](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#calculateBounds).
As far as I can understand, it should inherit `width`, `height`, `calculateBounds()`, `getBounds()`, etc.

However when I create a PIXI.Graphics instance, these properties seem to be missing:

```
var g = new PIXI.Graphics();
g.beginFill(0xFF9900);
g.drawRect(-50,-50,100,100);
g.endFill();

g.position.x = g.position.y = 300;

stage.addChild(g);

g.getBounds();
//throws
//VM847:1 Uncaught TypeError: g.getBounds is not a function
//    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

What's the simplest way to calculate the transformed bounding box of a Graphics object using pixi.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.
https://repl.it/@CurlyBrace/PixiBounds

The problem is probably in the version you are using. Are you sure its the last one? For example there is outdated package named "pixi".

Comment: You're totally right! I didn't realise I was using pixi 4.5.5. I've updated to 4.7.3 (and adjusted my scene to match the new API) and now the functions I see in the docs are present. Can't believe I haven't checked that :))